# What does this C# syntax do?

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

I am reading a post about mobile web development and ASP.NET MVC here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABetterASPNETMVCMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx.

In the article, Scott Hanselman goes through the process of creating his own view engine to render different views based on whether the site is requested from a mobile web browser or not.

In his `MobileHelpers` class, he has several methods with signatures that are very foreign to me. Here's an example:

```
        public static void AddMobile<T>(this ViewEngineCollection ves, Func<ControllerContext, bool> isTheRightDevice, string pathToSearch)        
        where T : IViewEngine, new()    
        {        
            ves.Add(new CustomMobileViewEngine(isTheRightDevice, pathToSearch, new T()));    
        }
```

I've worked a little bit with inline functions like this (I think thats what they're called) but this logic is eluding me. I don't understand the purpose of the `where T : ......` line either.

Could you guys help me understand what is happening here?

Comment: @James, already 4 answers saying exactly that. :) Also, `, not ' :)

Comment: @bzlm Ya, I was rushing and didn't pay attention.  Not sure why I didn't get the dialog saying there were other answers available.  Ah well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would help if you could identify which parts in particular are confusing to you. I've picked the two I think are the most likely based on your question, and explained those. If there is any other syntax that is confusing you, please edit your question to explain which.

### Explanation for `where T : IViewEngine, new()`

C# allows you to place [constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) on generic type parameters. You can read more about constraints [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx).

In your particular case, `where T : IViewEngine` means that whatever type `T` is must be a descendant of the `IViewEngine` type. `where T : new()` is special syntax that indicates that whatever type `T` is must have a default constructor.

### Explanation for `this ViewEngineCollection ves`

The keyword `this` means that the method `AddMobile` is an extension method to the `ViewEngineCollection` class. This means that in addition to being called as `AddMobile(someViewEngineCollection, ...)`, it can be called as `someViewEngineCollection.AddMobile(...)`. You can read more about extension methods [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Comment: This is correct. As another example, you could say `where T : Exception`, which would allow type `T` to be an Exception, or any class derived from Exception.

Comment: Those are the two. Thnaks for the additional resources as well.

Answer (score 5):

This is known as an extension method.  The `this` modifier on the first parameter allows the method to be called as if it's an instance method on the type `ViewEngineCollection.  For example

```
ViewEngineCollection col = ...;
col.AddMobile<SomeType>(() => true, "thepath");
```

The second item you mentioned, `where`, is known as a generic constraint.  It limits the set of types which can be used for `T` to those which have a public parameterless constructor and derive from `IViewEngine`

Comment: I didn't realize that about extension methods. At least, I knew it, but it never "clicked" with me. It's so simple that I do this with Html Helpers all the time. But, now I have a deeper understanding of what's happening!

Answer (score 1):

The `this` is for an extension method. So any reference to a `ViewEngineCollection` has an extension method called `AddMobile`.  The `where T : IViewEngine, new()` is called a generic constraint.

Answer (score -1):

Where the calling device contains identification information in its user agent details (this is typically the browser name or something in webapp the method is aiming to match up a custom view engine to the route table for that device.

It's a bit generic and without context can be quite confusing but each device identifies itself in a unique way (well unique by device name at least).

essentially this method is identifying the right veiw engine to use to handle the device information given.

Since everyone else is trying to explain constraints and generics i thought i would leave that to the pros ...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx

... best way really ...